# Is it possible to set resource quotas only for namespaces? [kubernetes]

Tags: kubernetes

We have 3 namespaces on a kubernetes cluster

```
dev-test / build / prod
```

I want to limit the resource usage for `dev-test` & `build` only. 
Can I set the resource quotas only for these namespaces without specifying (default-) resource requests & limits on the pod/container level?

If the resource usage on the limited namespaces is low, prod can use the rest completely, and it can grow only to a limited value, so prod resource usage is protected.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: dev-test
spec:
  hard:
    cpu: "2"
    memory: 8Gi
```

Is this enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set resource limits per namespace using ResourceQuota object:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: mem-cpu-demo
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "1"
    requests.memory: 1Gi
    limits.cpu: "2"
    limits.memory: 2Gi
```

From [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-memory-cpu-namespace/).

Comment: So I need both of them - the ResourceQuota to limit resources in the namespace, and the LimitRange for default resource requesting of pods/containers?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I removed it from the answer because you asked only about limiting resource usage, but you can see LimitRange documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/

Comment: when you define request/limit and there is no request/limit on pod/deployment yaml this will be default request/limit for pod in that space .. @hilsenrat shared the link with all details above/

Comment: Yes now I understand, if quotas are defined, default requests or requests on pod/deployment are mandatory. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can use kubeclt CLI as well to define resource quota** per namespace.

Example :

```
$ kubectl create namespace testquotaspace
namespace/testquotaspace created

$ kubectl create quota testquota -n testquotaspace --hard=cpu=1,memory=8Gi
resourcequota/testquota created

$ kubectl describe namespaces testquotaspace
Name:         testquotaspace
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

Resource Quotas
 Name:     testquota
 Resource  Used  Hard
 --------  ---   ---
 cpu       0     1
 memory    0     8Gi

No LimitRange resource.
```

**you can choose to limit the other objects you need as well like PODS/SERVICE/PVC etc** ..
Just run help on CLI and will have all details

```
$ kubectl create quota --help
Create a resourcequota with the specified name, hard limits and optional scopes

Aliases:
quota, resourcequota

Examples:
  # Create a new resourcequota named my-quota
  kubectl create quota my-quota
--hard=cpu=1,memory=1G,pods=2,services=3,replicationcontrollers=2,resourcequotas=1,secrets=5,persistentvolumeclaims=10
```

If you do need yamls you can generate as follow and pipe to a file as needed

```
$ kubectl create quota testquota -n testquotaspace --hard=cpu=1,memory=8Gi  --dry-run -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: testquota
  namespace: testquotaspace
spec:
  hard:
    cpu: "1"
    memory: 8Gi
```